# Filter objects in django which are added before or after a specific Hour of time

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I am using django-1.7 in my app. I have a model which has two DateTimeFields. Like

```
class Task(models.Model):
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    finish_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I want to filter the fields `start_time` and `end_time` with hours `gte` and `lte` so that i can get the queryset which contains Task objects which have to start at a particular time and have a to end at a particular time. What I tried in

```
Task.objects.filter(start_time__hour__gte=2)
Task.objects.filter(end_time__hour__lte=2)
```

But this query gives me error

```
    FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'hour' for DateTimeField or join on the field not permitted.
```

I have tried queryset.raw also which provides correct values but gives error when using with `django-filters` package.

```
def start_time_filter(self, queryset, value):
    if value.isdigit():
        return queryset.raw("select * from app_task WHERE TIME(`start_time`) >= '{0}';".format(value))

    return queryset.none()
```

Help will be appriciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this, but by reading the doc sounds like the `hour__gte=2` syntax is only added in django 1.9. Previous versions of django only allow exact lookup like `hour=2`. You might consider upgrading django and try again.

Regarding the raw query error, I don't know what error did you get, but django doc also has the syntax for that. You might look up on the exact sql statement because each sql statement for a database is different. This might solve your problem is you don't want to upgrade django.

[django doc about hour lookup in django 1.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#hour)

[django doc about hour lookup in django 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#hour)

Comment: Yes, This functionality is added in 1.9 only.

Comment: Trying to get some solution for this without upgrading to django-1.9